# Android-SQLite: How to deal with unique values?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, unique

I'm trying to write to a database, in my spec I had to ensure that there are no duplicates for a specific field. Great! I can just make the column unique.

But I have no idea how to deal with that after. If I use the application and accidentally insert a new value which happens to already exist, the app will just crash. How do I check that the value already exists before I try to update the database?

I feel like an if command would work, Buuuuut, How do you scan every value for that column on android anyway?

Comment: `If I use the application and accidentally insert a new value which happens to already exist, the app will just crash.` **Q:** How do you handle errors? **A:** by using `try ... catch [... finally]`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you propose that we can read all rows in a table, and for each row, check whether the value already exists. If not exist, insert, else, handle conflict.

Another way of doing it is using insertWithOnConflict() method. You can set various conflict resolution strategy such as:

- CONFLICT_ABORT
- CONFLICT_FAIL
- CONFLICT_IGNORE
- CONFLICT_NONE
- CONFLICT_REPLACE
- CONFLICT_ROLLBACK

I don't have any idea on the complexity of this method, but probably it is much better than reading all rows manually and check manually.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int)